# Which Boost Binary File *.a to Use in C++ Program

Tags: c++, boost, binary, codeblocks

I am running a C++ tutorial program using Codeblocks and I found out that in the program's build options under Linker settings/Link Libraries I can put both or either of the ff and the program compiles & runs without errors. What is the difference between the two?

`libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_77.dll.a`
OR
`libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_77.dll.a`

Comment: Most probably the one with `-d-` is for Debug build, and the other for Release build.

Comment: I expect the `-d-` one to be built `-g -O0` or `-g -Og` and the other one to be built `-O3`.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: Boost library documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Boost Debug and Release Libraries the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200760/are-boost-debug-and-release-libraries-the-same)