# Unhandled exception; Access violation reading location with MSVS 9.0 (VS 2008)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My application is crashing  when i am trying to call SetName() in the below code.

### main.cpp

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
    Schema * schemaExp = new Schema();

    //Application is getting crash when calling this function 
    schemaExp -> SetName("ExpSchema");

    string srctable;
    srctable=schemaExp->GetName();
    cout <<"\nConnection EXPORT using the target table:" << srctable.c_str()  << endl;
    delete schemaExp;
    return 0;
}
```

### Schema Class Definition:

```
using namespace std;
class Schema
{
   public:
   TELAPI_EXPORT void   SetName(string name); 
   TELAPI_EXPORT string     GetName(); 
   protected: 
   string tableName; 
};

void Schema::SetName(string name){ tableName = name; }

string Schema::GetName()
{
  return tableName;
}
```

I am using MSVS 9 (VS 2008). My application as well as shared library(dll)(I am using to link with my application) is also of c++ environment.Now observe the below cases:

1.when the shared library/dll is built in Debug mode and my application is also built in Debug mode 
Result: Application executed successfully

2.when the shared library/dll is built in Release mode and my application is also built in Release mode 
Result: Application executed successfully

3.when the **shared library/dll is built in Release mode** and my **application is built in Debug** mode 
Result:Application throws a crash report with following break statement.

Unhandled exception at 0x1003f3a5 in multiple.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00134000.

Note: The above code is just a part from my application. ***Schema Class Definition is from shared library and main.cpp from my application. Also, this problem seems to fail on Windows only, unix versions worked fine.***

**One more important thing if I comment out `schemaExp -> SetName("ExpSchema");` in main.cpp , the application passes in the above three cases, I mean any combination of release and debug build**

**In the entire code of my original application(of which above code is a part), only the above function call is troubling me**

**I guess something going wrong in using string as a parameter to function call, but also note when I wrote the sample program(not linking to shared library/dll) implementing the above scenario my application runs fine**

Completely struck over here. Unable to predict what's going wrong and what's causing access violation that too only in the #3 case.

Please help me in fixing this problem. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `void main` isn't legal. Use `int main`.

Comment: when the shared library/dll is built in Release mode and the application is built in Debug mode, it's not expected to work

Comment: @chris : Please tell me why `void main` is illegal, Thanks

Comment: @ABFORCE, Because the standard forbids it. *An implementation shall not predeﬁne the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
have a return type of type int...*

Comment: We already went through that in [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17564869/release-mode-vs-debug-mode-in-ms-visual-studio-windows).  Why are you repeating it?

Comment: I am sorry, you are no way wrong in asking me this question, but please observe the post clearly...both are errors are entirely different...what I specified in this post is my exact error and which hits when I am calling `schemaExp -> SetName("ExpSchema");`. To fix this I changed the function definition from here to there. There the problem is with destructor but here with the function call itself...

Comment: I want to know why I am getting these issues when I am using only the SetName() call and working fine in every other case...apart from release-debug combination(though may be a cause) of libraries, I think there is something wrong with the function call and its definition itself(please confirm)....Please tell me if you need any more details...Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would expect. Consider:

- The debug build and the release build use different run-time libraries in the background. So allocating and releasing memory for example will be done differently depending on the build you have selected.
- If you do not declare constructors or destructors to be imported or exported then they will be auto-generated and use the run-time with which the project is build that includes the shared lib.
- Depending on the build type certain macros might be set or not. For example the `NDEBUG` macro is set in release mode usually. This affects the not only the functions (and assertions) but sometimes even the size of data structures. If you have a checked STL implementation for example, then the iterators of a container may store a pointer to their container for internal validity checks.

As you can see, mixing Debug and Release is not a good thing. Just avoid it, if possible.